# Disabling automatic Android updates on an unrooted Samsung S22?

Tags: updates, ota-update

Is there any way to disable automatic Android updates (for the OS, not apps) on an unrooted Samsung S22 running Android 13?

I bought it through T-Mobile, and it's really driving me insane. The phone's overall performance is fine, but T-Mobile (not Samsung, the updates are explicitly T-Mobile-branded) forces Microsoft-eske automatic OS updates on me several times a week, which disables the phone for hours until I manually unlock it and it "finishes installing updates".

I tried some obvious solutions suggested on various blogs, like disabling `Settings->Software update->Auto download over Wi-fi`, but these options are either removed (thanks T-Mobile) or have no effect.

I use this phone for work as well as my personal alarm and for meeting notifications. Due to these updates, I've overslept when my alarms and meeting reminders don't start. I refuse to accept that a $900 phone has to be less capable than a $5 alarm clock.

Comment: I would assume that the main problem is that it reboots and you have to enter the lockscreen PIN the first time so that the encrypted user data files can be decrypted. So when you enter the PIN and then see the "finishes installing updates" message this means your phone has just rebooted. I don't know how Samsung handles updated but on Google phones this reboot is scheduled to the next night. So checking the phone before going to sleep would be enough.